# What are the security vulnerabilities (if any) with using HTML5 iframes

Tags: html, iframe

I'm migrating from one version of a web client to a newer version running on the same machine.

The web client will be primarily used on an internal LAN interface but there will be some exposure to the WAN also.

As a migratory step, I intend to include pages from the newer webclient in the older webclient structure. I was planning to use iframes for this.

Are there any potential security risks that I should be aware of before doing this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What browser is used internally. If it's IE6 there might be some, but otherwise, if the domain of the url loaded in the iframe is different from the one of the page containing the iframe, there is almost no way to communicate between the two, and those ways are secure. At least in modern browsers. So I don't see any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 iframes have sandboxing technology built in, but you have to enable it first. This means that XSS won't be an option, so if you're making iframe widgets that handle personal information, like Facebook do, as long as you do the usual stuff, there's nothing you should be concerned about.

Comment: Thanks desbest. What is the "usual stuff" one can do in a Facebook app implementation -- which will allow us to Not be concerned? Thanks for any specific details or pointers.

Comment: If you're making a Facebook application in php, you will have to do the _usual stuff_ that you would normally do in any other php script that you would make.

Comment: Thanks desbest. My question is: how to enable the html5 sandboxing?

Comment: http://www.idontplaydarts.com/2011/05/clickjacking-and-phishing-with-help-from-the-html5-javascript-sandbox/ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh563496.aspx http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/